# Incorrect byte range request

Tags: actionscript-3, http, flowplayer

I have some problems with byte range request. My flow player sends a request like:

```
Range: bytes=64313343-64313343
```

So could anybody explain me, why the unit bytes are equal? Therefore I have not range, therefor my seek is not working!

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid range - of exactly 1 byte. The end position is inclusive, which is pretty odd in computing world. In HTTP you cannot request a range of 0 bytes...

Comment: OK,Its clear. So again , why the unit bytes are equal !? Any idea ?